# Is there a way to prove that the second snippet below inserts an invisible declaration `struct S;` just before the function declaration?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The code below compiles ([demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dig0aSzloRL6REzg)), which proves that the function declaration `void f(struct S&);`inserts an invisible declaration (`struct S;`) in global scope, just before the function declaration, otherwise the second declaration (`extern S s;`) would fail to compile.

```
void f(struct S&);
extern S s;
```

I'm pretty sure the second code below also includes an invisible declaration (`struct S;`) just before the function declaration, but I can't find a way to prove this. Any suggestion?

```
struct S{};  
void f(struct S&);
```

The invisible declarations referred to above are mentioned in the Note in [[basic.scope.declarative]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope#declarative-4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure the second code below also includes an invisible declaration (`struct S;`) just before the function declaration, but I can't find a way to prove this. Any suggestion?
>
> ```
> struct S{};  
> void f(struct S&);
> ```

It does not. [[basic.lookup.elab]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.elab) describes how we determine if an *elaborated-type-specifier* declares a new type or refers to an existing one:

> If the *elaborated-type-specifier* is introduced by the *class-key* and this lookup does not find a previously declared *type-name*, or if the *elaborated-type-specifier* appears in a declaration with the form: *class-key* *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *identifier* `;` the *elaborated-type-specifier* is a declaration that introduces the *class-name* as described in [basic.scope.pdecl].

In this case, lookup *does* find a previously declared *type-name* `S` (that is, `::S`), so there is no declaration.

Regardless though, whether or not it behaves as if it re-declares `S` isn't observable:

```
struct S { }; // #1
struct S;     // #2
```

There's no difference in the behavior of this program if `#2` doesn't exist (outside of like... `__LINE__`, but in this case the declaration would be compiler-generated and so wouldn't affect that anyway).

Comment: Nevertheless,[\[basic.scope.pdecl\]p(7.2)](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.pdecl#7.2) seems to indicate that the compiler inserts the alluded invisible declaration, from this quote:  "if the elaborated-type-specifier is used in the decl-specifier-seq or parameter-declaration-clause of a function defined in namespace scope, the identifier is declared as a class-name in the namespace that contains the declaration;"

Comment: @Ayrosa The compiler does not insert invisible declarations anywhere. The `struct S` in `void f(struct S&);` *is* a declaration of `S` if `S` has not been declared before…

Comment: I started a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/g3ddJ6RUDKU/CABQsJgZAQAJ) in C++ std-discussion about the possible contradiction between [basic.lookup.elab]/2 and [basic.scope.pdecl]/(7.2).